# List[Future[List[Int]]] to List[Int]

Tags: scala, future

With a large `List[Int]`, I decided to use `List#grouped(Int)` to get a `List[List[Int]]`. Then, I mapped over it, applying a function, `List[Int] => Future[List[Int]]`. My intention was to apply a function concurrently to the sub-lists.

Now I have `List[scala.concurrent.Future[List[Int]]]`.

Given that type, I'd like to get `List[Int]` to collect the results.

What's the idiomatic way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean `Future[List[Int]]` instead of just `List[Int]`. In which case, you would use `Future.sequence` to map `List[Future[A]]` to `Future[List[A]]`, then `flatten` the `List` contained in the single `Future`.

```
val list: List[Future[List[Int]]] = ...

Future.sequence(list).map(_.flatten)
```

And if for some reason just want to remove the `Future`, then you'll need to block to get it.

```
Await.result(Future.sequence(list).map(_.flatten), Duration.Inf)
```

Comment: Thanks. `sequence` was the key to my question, as you pointed out. `sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]`  per [Typeclassopedia](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia?)

Answer (score 1):

The `sequence` approach  suggested by @m-z will work, but the cool/idiomatic way to do it is to use scalaz's `traverseM` instead of `map` with the function:

```
def myFunction(li: List[Int]): Future[List[Int]] = ...
val myList: List[List[Int]] = ...

import scalaz._, Scalaz._

myList.traverseM(myFunction) //returns a Future[List[Int]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val futures = List[Future[List[Int]]]
Future.fold(futures)(List.empty) { (l, r) =>
    l ++ r
} onComplete {
    case Success(r) => println(r)
    case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace()
}
```